# Button image action

Tags: javascript, html, button

I have an issues with an image type button, here is my code:

```
<script>
function test5(){

    var u = document.getElementById("id").value; 
    var url = "exceljsp.jsp";
    url += "?id=" + u;
    javascript:window.location.href = url;
}
</script>
<form id="form" name="form" mrthode="get">
            <table align="center">
                <td> <p>Code FRs </p> </td><td>  <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="" /></td>
                <td>                         <td>
                <td> <p>Nom ou RS </p> </td><td><input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" value="" /></td>
            </table>
<input type="image" src='excel.png' name="look excel table"  onclick="test5();">
```

The `javascript:window.location.href = url;` does not appear to be working. When I put `<input type="button" name="look excel table" onclick="test5();">` it works. but if I put button type image  it does'nt work.

Comment: So, what is the problem?

Comment: I can't execute test5();

Comment: What the onclick isn't firing?

Comment: Change input[type="img"] to button and style the button through css.

Comment: I can't execute :javascript:window.location.href=url; but whene I put <input type="button" name="look excel table"  onclick="test5();"> it works.

Comment: `javascript:` prefix is redundant there.

Comment: Nope, your onclick will work and it will popup the alert.

Comment: only the pop but not the href action

Comment: please add the javascript tag to the question

Comment: What I understood from your question that alert is working and 'window.location.href = url' is not. It may be due to the 'url' variable , please check whether url is in correct format or not

Answer (score 1):

Your problem must be elsewhere as the function is called just fine. Check this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Claudius/JD9Rj/1/) where I just pasted in your code:

```
<script>
function test5(){
    alert("oui");
    var u = document.getElementById("id").value; 
    var url = "exceljsp.jsp";
    url += "?id=" + u;
    javascript:window.location.href = url;
}
</script>

<input type="image" src='excel.png' name="look excel table"  onclick="test5();">
```

You do however have a few errors in your HTML, namely syntax error in the name attribute (white spaces are not allowed) and a missing alt attribute.

Also, the html element with `id='id'` is not visible in your question.

Answer (score -1):

It's a bad practice to use onCLick event in your HTML

Instead use

```
<input id="testButton" type="image" src='excel.png' name="look excel table">

$("#testButton").click(function() {
       alert("oui");
       var u=document.getElementById("id").value; 
       var url = "exceljsp.jsp";
       url += "?id=" + u;
       window.location.href=url;
});
```

Should works just fine

Comment: This will only work with Jquery, the question is not flagged with jquery.

Comment: You can add Event listner with pure JS. jQuery dosen't change the general meaning of the answer

Comment: the problem is with the type image(the same whene I use CSS or <button><img></button>) , I tried input button standart and its fine.please help

Comment: Jquery does change the general meaning of the answer, i.e. your answer **will not work**!

Comment: <form id="form" name="form" mrthode="get">
                <table align="center">
                    <td> <p>Code FRs </p> </td><td>  <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="" /></td>
                    <td>                         <td>
                    <td> <p>Nom ou RS </p> </td><td><input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" value="" /></td>
                </table>
                 <br/>
            <br/>
            <a href="#?h=900" rel="popup_name" class="poplight"><img src="ajouter.png" alt="AJOUTER"></a>

Comment: no, this is my first code and its'not working only the pop appears but the rest of the code is blocked. this code work only when i use input type button without image whatsoever(CSS OR TYPE IMG PR <IMG>).

Answer (score -1):

Where your id comes from?

i have tried with an input field with id value 7. so its working fine.

```
<script>
function test5(){
  alert("oui");
  var u = document.getElementById("id").value; 
  var url = "exceljsp.jsp";
  url += "?id=" + u;
  javascript:window.location.href = url;
}
</script>

 <input type="image" src='excel.png' name="look excel table"  onclick="test5();">
 <input type="text" value="7" name="id" id="id">
```

can you please paste the entire code to show where your id value is coming from

Comment: '<table align="center">
                <td> <p>Code FRs </p> </td><td>  <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="" /></td>
                <td>                         <td>
                <td> <p>Nom ou RS </p> </td><td><input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" value="" /></td>
            </table><input type="image" src="exel.png" onclick="test5();">'

Comment: so the code is working when you give an id value: <script>
function test5(){
  alert("oui");
  var u = document.getElementById("id").value; 
  var url = "exceljsp.jsp";
  url += "?id=" + u;
  javascript:window.location.href = url;
}
</script>
<table align="center"> 
<td> <p>Code FRs </p> </td>
<td> <input type="text" name="id" id="id" value="" /></td> 
<td> <td> 
<td> <p>Nom ou RS </p> </td>
<td><input type="text" name="nom" id="nom" value="" /></td> 
</table>
<input type="image" src="exel.png" onclick="test5();">

Comment: no, this is my first code and its'not working only the pop appears but the rest of the code is blocked. this code work only when i use input type button without image whatsoever(CSS OR TYPE IMG PR <IMG>).